# Why is this .not() selector not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sidebar responsive menu that opens when clicked on a button.
The menu has dropdown sub-menus and uses twitter bootstrap template.

I am trying to hide the menu when clicked anywhere on the screen except the menu-button and the menu itself.

But the exception of clicking on menu does not work. It hides even when clicked over the menu. The problem according to me lies in the .not() selector.

What may be wrong here?

The code is:

**CSS**

```
.menu-click
{
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 1px #ffcccc;
}

.mobile-menu
{
    top: 50px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    animation-duration:0.5s;
   -o-animation-duration:0.5s;
   -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
   -moz-animation-duration:0.5s;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){

    $("html").not('.mobile-menu').click(function(){
        $(".mobile-menu").removeClass("animated fadeInLeft").addClass("animated fadeOutLeft")
    });
    $(".menu-click").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`jQuery.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filters on the matched elements you're calling it on. What the code in your question is asking for is all *`<html>`* elements that are *not* `.mobile-menu` elements.

You probably want something like this:

```
$("ul").not('.mobile-menu').click(...)
```

---

After discussion in the comments, if you have a `div` with `.mobile-menu` on it and you want to check if `.mobile-menu` is not on it, you need to identify the `div` in another manner as well, such as adding a `.menu` class.

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
<div class="menu mobile-menu">...</div>
```

In this case you could select the non-`.mobile-menu` one with:

```
$('.menu').not('.mobile-menu').click(...)
```

Not adding the `.menu` class and using `$('.div').not('.mobile-menu')` would select every single `div` on the page that does not have `.mobile-menu`, not just the one you're interested in.

Comment: But that is what I want i.e., clicking on "all html elements that are not .mobile-menu elements" to hide the menu. You selected "ul" instead of "html". It does not work here!

Comment: By `html` elements I mean `<html>`. There should only be one of these in the document (the root node).

Comment: Ok, it should not use "html" selector then. But ".mobile-menu" isn't a <ul> element either. Should I try "div" selector because ".mobile-menu" is a <div> element?

Comment: If `.mobile-menu` is on a `div` then yes, you likely want `$('div.menu').not('.mobile-menu')`.

Comment: Done! I added a menu class to the wrapper-class as well as to the .mobile-menu. That worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Or even better, use the :not pseudo selector, in your case:

```
$('html:not(.mobile-menu)')...
```

or

```
$('body:not(.mobile-menu)')...
```

for that matter.

If that doesn't work, you can always go the long way, and monitor clicks on the whole body, and then check in the handler if the parent is the .mobile-menu class:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('.mobile-menu').length === 0) {
        //do stuff here
    }
})
```

Comment: Tried that already, the problem seems to be in selecting the right element to be "clicked" upon. "html" here is the problem

Comment: Check my latest edit. Have you tried listening for clicks on the body or the document?